# Multi-PHP how to install php 5.3 with PEAR and extensions on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, pdo, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed a new server which comes with php 5.5. however one of my older projects requires php 5.3.

So I installed php 5.3 with

```
wget http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.28.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror
tar -xvjf mirror
cd php-5.3.28
./configure --prefix /usr/local/php.5.3.28
make
make install
```

However php_mysql and php_pdo_mysql extensions are missing. So I was wondering how to install them into a custom php build on a server running with multiple php versions?

Server is running on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've had to migrate servers with very old php code that needed PHP version 5.3 to run it. Since my virtual machine provider uses the latest and greatest and has a policy on not allowing old linux distros I had to use Ubuntu 14.04. Problem is, as you said, it comes shipped with php 5.5 so I had to come up with a way that would allow me to get php 5.3 up and running. After searching the internet for a while I found a variety of solutions that I tried the first was what you did install from sources. That indeed installed php 5.3 but then I ran into the same issues you seem to have so I tried another solution that was recommended and used CGI to support php 5.3. I thought I had found the ultimate solution to this conundrum yet after a while I realized it was very unstable and things where buggy. So I thought of how I could resolve this issue and here is what I came up with. Before I reveal how I properly installed php 5.3 on my Ubuntu 14.04 I'd like to say that it's probably not the most elegant way to do this but I spent so much time on what should be an easy task that in retrospect it's a fair solution. Anyways here goes:

```
    $ cd /etc/apt/
    $ sudo cp sources.list sources.list.14_04
```

Use your favorite editor and edit sources.list and delete content of file then paste following into your file (this is a sources.list of a Ubuntu 12.04)

```
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release     amd64 (20120817.3)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120817.3)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120817.3)]/ precise main restricted

    #deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120817.3)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
    #deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120817.3)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
    #deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120817.3)]/ precise main restricted

    # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
    # newer versions of the distribution.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
    deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

    ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
    ## distribution.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
    deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

    ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
    ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
    deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
    deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

    ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
    ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
    ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
    ## security team.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
    deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
    deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

    ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
    ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
    ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
    ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
    ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
    deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
    deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
    deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

    ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
    ## 'partner' repository.
    ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
    ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
    # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
    # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

    ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
    ## 'extras' repository.
    ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
    ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
    # deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
    # deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Now save and quit.

```
    $ sudo apt-get clean
    $ sudo apt-get check
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install php5 php-mysql

    Install whatever package you want to work with php version 5.3

    $ php -version
    PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:05:04)
    Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

If you need to install mysql-server you'll have to switch back your sources.list to the sources.list.14_04 file

```
    $ sudo mv sources.list sources.list.12_04
    $ sudo mv sources.list.14_04 sources.list
    $ sudo apt-get clean
    $ sudo apt-get check
    $ sudo apt-get update
```

Other than that you should have a Ubuntu 14.04 with php version 5.3 and php_mysql extensions running fine. Hope this helps !

Comment: I have same problem, I need to downgrade to PHP 5.3, I will give a try.